# streaming or listening to live audio from mic over apache server possible?

Tags: linux, apache, firewall, audio-streaming, live-streaming

I have the Fedora13 linux home server with Zoneminder for my own home security system.  I can monitor the home visually with many webcam and ip cams video. But I can not listen to any sound like water detection alarm or fire or burglar alarm.

Is there any way to listen to live sound coming from the microphone of the home server over the internet?  I already have the apache home server for the zoneminder, so, I think it has to be with apache server,  like module since the port 80 bound to apache server can not be shared with other application..   Due to the firewalls at home and work, and due to the single dynamic ip address, I see no other way but with apache server.

If I can embed the audio listening application on the zoneminder web page, it would be most desirable. But, for now, I just want to listen to any sound at home real time anyway I can. Separate application over the internet is fine as long as it is real time and over the port 80 like VNC over SSH.

I looked at Icecast2 and Ices, but due to firewalls, it seems difficult or impossible. I considered 'sox' linux application to detect any sound and send the sound file as an email attachment, but it dose not seem to fit my need quite well.

I would appreciate very much any suggestions.  Thank you.

Comment: Apache `mod_proxy` can hook in your other servers, running on ports other than 80, and make them accessible on port 80. Or you could just use a simple CGI.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will look into mod_proxy. But do you think with mod_proxy it is acheivable what I am trying to do? Thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could get Icecast (for example) through your firewall problems using mod_proxy. But really, this doesn't seem like a programming question, and would probably be better asked on [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thank you. I will look into mod_proxy and Icecast.  I am sorry that I posted my question here. I did not know the Unix.SE existed. Thank you very much again for the new info.

Comment: No problem. Check out http://stackexchange.com/sites to see all the sites on the StackExchange network.

Comment: Icecast is just HTTP.  No reason why you can't proxy that with Apache, but I'd just open it up on another port, such as 8080, that probably won't be firewalled.  Also, try 443.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an ssh access to a Linux machine at home that is equipped with a microphone, you can do the following to listen live to it surrounding sound/noise.

assuming you have **arecord** installed on your home Linux machine, and **aplay**  installed on your local machine (both arecord and aplay exists on Linux Ubuntu)

```
ssh username@your_home_device_ip 'arecord -f cd -t wav' | aplay -
```

Hope this help.